# How to Hide/Show a text field in titanium alloy?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

Is there any way to show/hide the text field based on the selected input. I have one radio button question is there If user select Other option from that question then I need to display one textbox to enter the value. Is it possible.

**View**

```
<TextField id="locationText" hintText="Enter Reason"></TextField>
```

**Style:**

```
"#locationText": {
    width: '90%',
    top: '25dp',
    height: 40
}
```

**Controller:**

```
button.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
      if(radioGroup.selectedValue == 'Other')
       {
        // Here I need to show the text field, If the selected value is not Other the text field should be hidden
       }
});
```

Any suggestions please

Comment: set opacity to 0 then use the fadeIn method? http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Alloy.builtins.animation

Comment: why not use the hide and show functions? http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextArea-method-hide

Comment: first set the property `visible` to `false`, then on selection of radio button. toggle the `visible` property. http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.TextField-property-visible

Comment: How to use visible property as toggle

Comment: @Precious  

View : 

    <TextField id="locationText" visible=false hintText="Enter Reason"></TextField>

Controller :

    button.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
      if(radioGroup.selectedValue == 'Other')
       {
           $.locationText.visible = true;
       }else{
           $.locationText.visible = false;
       }
    });

Answer (score 3, accepted):

View :

```
<TextField id="locationText" visible=false hintText="Enter Reason"></TextField>
```

Controller :

```
button.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
    if(radioGroup.selectedValue == 'Other'){ 
        $.locationText.visible = true;        
    }else{
        $.locationText.visible = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Please suggest some answer for the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26374903/how-to-bind-the-data-in-to-label-in-titanium-alloy.