# How to bind the data in to label in Titanium alloy?

Tags: javascript, titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How can I bind data from controller to xml, My code is as follows,

**View:**

```
  <Collection src="respondentAge"/>
    <Label id="question"></Label>
```

**Styles**

```
".question":{
    font:{
        fontSize:18,
        fontWeight:'normal'
    },
    color:"#000",
    left:10,
    height:Ti.UI.SIZE
}
```

**Controller**

```
     var agenames = Alloy.Collections.respondentAge;
     agenames.on("reset", function() {
       var agenamesLength = agenames.length;
       var question; 
       for (var i = 0; i < agenamesLength; i++) {
            question = agenames.at(i).get("quesion");
         // I need to bind the 'agenames.at(i).get("quesion")' value in to label in 
       }
      });
   agenames.fetch({
       query:"SELECT * FROM respondentAge WHERE languageID ='1';"
  });
```

The question text is coming from the database, So for for question I have added the label and I'm retrieving the value from database and I need to set the label value as retrieving value.

How can I do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose you use the `setText(text)` property of Label. You can read more about it here: [Label docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Titanium.UI.Label-method-setText)

```
agenames.on("reset", function() {
    var agenamesLength = agenames.length;
    var question; 
    for (var i = 0; i < agenamesLength; i++) {
        question = agenames.at(i).get("quesion");
        $.question.setText(question);
    }
});
```